# how to write a query which deletes a particular record in a table and store that record in another backup table in sql

Tags: sql

how to write a query that deletes a particular record in a table and store that record in another backup table in sql

Comment: It sounds like you want an `on delete` trigger in your table.

Comment: your question not enough clear. how to write backups? where is your tried query? if you need help for how to ask question please read help center.

Comment: This is always accomplished in SQL in two steps, an Insert to your backup table and a Delete from your source table.  Gordon Linoff is suggesting you chain the insert to each delete event via a trigger.  Your other alternative is a scripting tool to execute the two statements one after the other.  The best solution will depend on your data base which you did not reveal.

Comment: Please tag the database you are using - different options are available depending, eg SQL Server allows this in the one statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a transaction and put your Insert and Delete in separate batches but
in a single transaction:

```
BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRAN
 
    --firstly, inserted into backup table
INSERT INTO TestBackup
(
    Name
)
SELECT t.Name FROM Test AS t
WHERE t.Id=1

--then delete it
DELETE FROM Test
WHERE Id=1

    
COMMIT TRAN 
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

ROLLBACK TRAN
PRINT('transaction rolled back.')

END CATCH
```

Or use `Output` clause in a single batch :

```
DELETE FROM [Test]
OUTPUT DELETED.Name INTO TestBackup
(NAME)
WHERE id=2
```

`Test` table definition is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK__Test__3214EC07A5870A1E] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```